# How can I find an AVR chip with built-in RF transceiver?

Tags: microcontroller, avr, rf, wireless

I'm going to build a couple of small devices that communicate wirelessly. To simplify construction, I've decided to look for a chip (preferrably on a breakout board) that combines a programmable microcontroller with an RF transceiver module.

I've found the [nRF24LU1+](http://www.nordicsemi.com/eng/Products/2.4GHz-RF/nRF24LU1P), but I'd prefer an AVR microcontroller since I've used those before and know how to program them. How can I search for such chips/board? I've tried search terms such as "avr rf module" and "combined avr rf", but have only managed to find RF modules.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Atmel has dedicated [single chip solutions](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/Wireless/single-chip_solutions.aspx) for wireless communication based on the AVR ATmega series.

They also have other architectures (such as ARM), which can be found generally from their [MCU Wireless Solutions](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/wireless/default.aspx) page.

If you're looking for a 2.4 GHz breakout board (evaluation kit) you might be interested in something like the [RZRAVEN](http://www.atmel.com/tools/RZRAVEN.aspx).

([Other evaluation kits.](http://www.atmel.com/products/microcontrollers/wireless/default.aspx?tab=tools))

Comment: Thanks! I checked these out, but as a hobbyist I think soldering the VFQFN packages would be too much of an obstacle for me.